# How to provide direct server SSH access using public static ip without internal ip

Tags: static-ip

I have a /29 static public ip pool. 5 ip are usable. I assigned one static ip to my router, and i don't want to use this ip for route to external server ip.

We are doing home server hosting business now my 1 client required Direct Server SSH access using public ip without internal ip. how can i do that.

I'm using tp link business router, but in this router we don't have any features like this. Before this i am using 1:1 NAT for providing dedicated servers to my clients using nat route external public ip to server internal private ip. But this clients need public ip as a internal ip.

Server have centos 7 operating systems. I tried many things, but still am not able to do that. I'm new in this please do something.

Please tell me any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Port forwarding? Tell your router to forward TCP/IP port 22 from the external static IP to the server?

Comment: How many ports do you have which are directly connected to the internet? Usually they are called a WAN interface. But exposing a server directly to the internet comes with a lot of security risks. I would recommend getting an VPS at hosting company or hosting the server in a datacenter (collocation)

Comment: How is the /29 assigned to you? Is it routed to your IP, or is it merely available for you?

Comment: @tsc_chazz how can i do that without internal server ip

Comment: @Prince Negi your only choice would be connecting the server directly to he internet. And as has been mentioned, that is a serious security risk. But if that's what your client wants... Get a simple wired switch. Connect ISP equipment, WAN port of router and server to switch. Assign one of your four remaining IP addresses to your client's server.